# Is H3 adequate for generic sphere tilling?

Tags: h3, sky

Is it possible to use the H3 grid system for celestial tilling? I want to use the (alpha, delta)=(right ascension, declinaison)  coordinate system ([equatorial coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system)) to assign a point/galaxy to a tile and then collect all the points (galaxies) of a particular tile, find the neighboring tiles, and get an unique indexing of the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine, as long as you have function to transform equatorial coordinates into lat/long coordinates. The inputs for H3 are expected to be lat/long points, specified as either degrees (for most of the bindings, e.g. `h3-js` and `h3-py`), or radians (for the core C library). Assuming you have a function to translate the `(ascension, declination)` tuple to a `(lat, long)` tuple, then H3 should be entirely adequate as a grid system for any spherical coordinates.

The only Earth-centric aspects of H3 are:

- The initial orientation of the icosahedron the grid is based on, which is optimized to place the vertices in Earth's oceans
- Any functions like `hexArea` or `edgeLength` which output units of kilometers or meters based on the Earth's radius.

Other than these, the grid system should work for any spherical context.

Comment: Great! So I will try. Is there a skeleton to get some visualisaton of the whole sphere and zoom on my (lat, long) points? Concerning `hexArea` and `edgeLength` I guess so I can rescale by 1/R^2 or 1/R with R=6000km or so (if yes, what is the exact value used in H3?) Concerning the global orientation, does the Noth/South pole are filed with a pentagon?

Comment: I forgot to ask: is there by chance a Scala interface?

Comment: The exact radius used by H3 is here: https://github.com/uber/h3/blob/master/src/h3lib/include/constants.h#L59

Comment: The icosahedron uses a version of the Dymaxion layout, which is not oriented based on the poles, but instead focused on putting vertices in oceans. I don’t think either pole is covered by a pentagon at the coarsest resolution (I’d need to double check, but if they were it would be incidental, as the vertices are not aligned with poles)

Comment: Known bindings are listed here: https://h3geo.org/docs/community/bindings - there isn’t a Scala binding, but I think Scala can use the Java bindings?

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot. concerning the Dymaxion layout I was wandering if there is a (lat,long) transformation one can used from H3 to be in a system with pentagons at poles (N & S) and a petagon located near equator at long=0 ?

Comment: No, that’s not possible, due to the shape of the icosahedron. See illustrations in http://webpages.sou.edu/~sahrk/sqspc/pubs/gdggs03.pdf - you have to choose pentagons at poles or at the equator, you can’t have both

Comment: To find a translation, simply find one of the res 0 pentagons using getPentagonIndexes and get the translation from its center to a pole of your choice

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is not just a translation but rotations,, no?

Comment: Yes, I meant a rotational translation, which maybe is misusing the term `translation`.